# Javascript global objects included in d8.exe

Tags: javascript, v8

I know V8 only include a subset of JavaScript global objects that we commonly use in the browsers, so global objects like `console/window/document` are not available in `d8.exe`. Functions like `setTimeout` are not available too (in fact, I can't find a way to replace this function).

I can do something like `if ("console" in this) { ... }` to check if `console` object is available or not, but this is not very elegant in my opinion. Is there a list that specified what is included and what is not? Or even better, a list of workarounds?

Comment: The word "syntax" is not appropriate. What you're asking about is the JavaScript global environment. That said, the answer is yes, you can simply check to see whether things like `document` and `window` are defined.

Comment: Well, the global symbols and APIs of web browsers and Node.js and other JavaScript runtime environments are generally documented, if that's what you mean. The most reliable way for your code to adapt, however, is definitely for it to make those explicit inelegant tests. Standards and specifications change over time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

V8, and thus d8, implements all of the libraries defined in the EcmaScript language specification ([Ecma 262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm)) and the EcmaScript internationalization API specification ([Ecma 402](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-402.htm)). In addition, d8 implements a couple of ad-hoc I/O functions that are mainly intended for V8's test suite, and should rather not be relied upon.

Comment: Before I read your answer, I already found out most of the global objects by checking `src/d8.cc` (many useful IO functions!) and run `strings d8.exe > list.txt`. The specification you showed me fills the remaining gaps. Thanks!